# Calling Method from Extended Class in ArrayList [Java]

Tags: java, class, arraylist

In short, what I am trying to do is save multiple extended classes to an `ArrayList` so I can call them more easily.

But whenever I try to call a method from an extended class in an `ArrayList`, I get an error saying the parent class does not have the method that only the extended class has but none for the method that was inherited by the extended class.

I think it may have to do with what type I gave the `ArrayList`.

Would it be possible to call a method form an extended class in an `ArrayList` or would I need to use a different approach?

```java
// Parent Class
public class Parent {
    public char checkA() {
        return 'Y';
    }
}

// Extended Class
public class Child extends Parent{
    public int checkB() {
        return 5;
    }
}

// Display Class
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Display{
    public static void main (String args[]){
        ArrayList<Parent> all = new ArrayList<Parent>();
        Child c = new Child();
        all.add(c);
        
        System.out.println(all.get(0).checkA());
        
        System.out.println(all.get(0).checkB());    
    }
}
```

Comment: "so I can call them more easily" - what would be your "hard" way when this is not easy?
Also do you mean "inherited" class when you say "extended", so do you refer to the `extends` keyword with "extended" ?

Comment: Maybe it would help to understand the problem that you want to solve with the `ArrayList` when you add "multiple extended classes" (as you wrote in your question) to your code example.

Comment: Each element in [`ArrayList`] `all` is an instance of `Parent` - even thought its actual type is `Child` - which means that it only knows about the methods in class `Parent`. In order to invoke methods in class `Child` you need to cast the element (in the `ArrayList`) to `Child`, i.e. `System.out.println(((Child) all.get(0)).checkB()); `